# Orika Custom Mapper

Tags: java, orika

I am new to Orika mapping tool. I have written a custom mapper, but Orika is not using it. It's not throwing any errors.  Even simple `if/else` block in the custom mapper is not working. I am not sure how to debug.

```
MapperFactory.classMap(A.class, B.class)
.customize(
        new CustomMapper<Class A, Class B>()
        {
            @Override
            public void mapAtoB(
                A from,
                B to,
                MappingContext context)
            {
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(from.getfield1()))
                {
                    to.setXXX(from.getfield1());
                }
                else
                {
                    to.setXXX(from.getfield2());
                }

            }
        })
        .register()
```

Comment: Please show your full setup of MapperFactor and A and B classes.

Comment: Thanks Adam!!! MapperFactory.classMap(A.class, B.class)..customize(
        new CustomMapper<Class A, Class B>()
        {
            @Override
            public void mapAtoB(
                A from,
                B to,
                MappingContext context)
            {
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(from.getfield1()))
                {
                    to.setXXX(from.getfield1());
                }
                else
                {
                    to.setXXX(from.getfield2());
                }

            }
        }).register()

Comment: Also I have created more than one such custom classMap with same signature. I think that was wrong. How many custom classMap can be created inside a mapper class? Each classMap should have different signature? In my case I have created 4 custom class maps with same signatures only the last classMap is getting executed. How can I create different custom class maps when main input and output is A and B? How to make sure that each of the custom logic is executed without any issues?

Comment: Please use the "edit" link underneath your original question to edit it and put the code there instead of the comment - as it is now, it's totally illegible. You can have only one custom mapper (last one wins). You can implement yourself a composite mapper that takes a list of mappers and executes them one after the other.

Comment: Do you have any documentation link for the composite mapper creation?

Comment: That's something you have to implement yourself, not available out of the box. Sample of composite pattern implementation: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite/java/2